# struct.unpack on a bytearray that works under Python 2.6.6, 2.7 and 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the test code:

```
import struct
buf = bytearray(b'\xef\xf8\t\xf2')
number = struct.unpack("<I", buf)[0]
```

How do I cleanly make it work both under Python 2.6 and Python 3.3? The problem is that struct.unpack in Python 2.6 seems to expect a str object (not unicode), so the only way I managed to come up with in order to get it working on both versions is:

```
buf_raw = bytearray(b'\xef\xf8\t\xf2')
buf_decoded = buf_raw.decode('latin1')
buf_encoded = buf_decoded.encode('latin1')
number = struct.unpack("<I", buf_encoded)[0]
```

...though I'm abusing the fact that `latin1` translates every 0-255 ASCII character to itself. What's the better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just call `bytes`?

```
number = struct.unpack('<I', bytes(buf))[0]
```

In Python 2.6:

```
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Aug 13 2012, 22:19:05) 
...
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('<I', bytes(bytearray(b'ABCD')))
(1145258561,)
```

In Python 3.3:

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, May 21 2013, 11:50:47) 
...
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('<I', bytes(bytearray(b'ABCD')))
(1145258561,)
```

Comment: How to handle it while double back slash issue.. For example  b'\\xef\\xf8\\t\\xf2'..